# Meteor.js HTTP.get to fetch JSON quotes and to parse the results seem to contain a callback function

Tags: javascript, json, meteor

I am trying to fetch data in Meteor.js from 126.com. Here is an example:

`http://api.money.126.net/data/feed/1000001,money.api`

and that will get back the following(one can test by opening above url in browser):

`_ntes_quote_callback({"1000001":{"code": "1000001", "percent": 0.042661, "high": 14.6, "askvol3": 318361, "askvol2": 93200, "askvol5": 214900, "askvol4": 62327, "price": 14.42, "open": 13.88, "bid5": 14.38, "bid4": 14.39, "bid3": 14.4, "bid2": 14.41, "bid1": 14.42, "low": 13.75, "updown": 0.59, "type": "SZ", "bidvol1": 459480, "status": 0, "bidvol3": 1713089, "bidvol2": 518100, "symbol": "000001", "update": "2015/01/21 15:34:15", "bidvol5": 508800, "bidvol4": 436678, "volume": 194053037, "askvol1": 90420, "ask5": 14.47, "ask4": 14.46, "ask1": 14.43, "name": "\u5e73\u5b89\u94f6\u884c", "ask3": 14.45, "ask2": 14.44, "arrow": "\u2191", "time": "2015/01/21 15:34:09", "yestclose": 13.83, "turnover": 2758192756.95} });`

I can get the contents. The problem comes with the leading "_ntes_quote_callback" which I think I am expected to set up a function using that name and return the the params? How? Thanks for any suggestions.

I'm very new to javascript and html so that I tried with some code though can't make it. I've tried the following:

at the client side

`_ntes_quote_callback = (jsonobj)-> jsonobj
stock = Session.get 'stock'
Meteor.call 'getQuote', stock, (err, results)->
    if err then return
    console.log results.content
    Session.set 'quote', JSON.parse results.content.val()`

and server side:

`if Meteor.isServer
    Meteor.methods
        getQuote: (stock) ->
            url = "http://api.money.126.net/data/feed/#{stock}"
            HTTP.call 'GET', url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to supply a query string param specifying the callback (or none), but if there are any API docs they're in Mandarin (I think), which rules out reading them for me.

However, even failing that you can just manipulate the returned data:

```
var regex = /^_ntes_quote_callback\((.*)\);$/,
    rawContent = HTTP.get(url).content,
    json = regex.exec(rawContent.content) && JSON.parse(regex.exec(rawContent.content)[1]);
```

The variable `json` should then be an object containing your data (apologies, I don't do CoffeeScript).

Comment: Thanks for your instructions. Sorry for Coffee script. There is no api docs found as it often happens with local website. So I should learn jQuery first and at least can use your suggested secondary approach!

Comment: Thank you richsilv and I'm trying to understand your sample code.

Comment: Solved. Thanks to richsilv